# Can't extend user models in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django

The admin console doesn't show me the `UserProfile` in Django Admin. There are no errors that show up. I reloaded my server but it still doesn't show in the console.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)`
```

`admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from account.models import UserProfile

admin.site.register(UserProfile)`
```

Comment: So you want to have some sort of a form for `UserProfile` in Django Admin, right?

Comment: yes @SeanFrancisN.Ballais

Comment: Okay, hang on. I'm writing an answer for that.

Comment: Are you logged in with a superuser?

Comment: yes @schwobaseggl

Comment: Then your registration of the  model should be enough. I assume you only have the django default admin site in your urls, not a custom one?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Doesn't he need to create a class based on `UserChangeForm`? Something along the lines of [this](https://github.com/seanballais/SAElections/blob/master/SAElections/voting/admin.py).

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais Normally not. Django should register a default `ModelAdmin` when you register a `Model` like that.

Comment: @schwobaseggl What about the fields? Does Django automatically include the fields in`UserProfile` to the form in the admin?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais Yup, all the ones that are not explicitly `editable=False` in the model definition,

Comment: @schwobaseggl Woah. That's odd. In your models, using `User.add_to_class()` instead of `field = Field()` doesn't make a difference when it comes to the admin, right?

Comment: @Balaji.J.B Can you debug in your console the content of `admin.site._registry[UserProfile]`.

Comment: Yes @SeanFrancisN.Ballais you are right, it should register but I don't know where the mistake is happening. Trying to fix this but can't do it.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais it showing me NameError: name 'admin' is not defined. When I debug in the console.

Comment: @Balaji.J.B Try checking my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48246983/1116098). It might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an admin model to your UserProfile like this example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from account.models import UserProfile

@admin.register(UserProfile)
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'description', 'city', 'website', 'phone')
    # Other instance overrides come in this class and some new methods
```

Comment: Thanks for your codes, but it doesn't work for me. @Chiheb Nexus

Comment: @Balaji.J.B which django version do you use ?

Comment: I using python 3 and Django 2.0.1 @Chiheb Nexus

Comment: @Balaji.J.B, well this code will run perfectly in your box. if not share what kind if errors you have

Comment: Actually, the weird thing is I have an error, If I have, I would solve. I cant find a single error in Pycharm and I tried all possible way. If you want to have look, you can have my TeamViewer Id and look. Really weird, It is killing my brain for past 5 hours.

Comment: @Balaji.J.B Let's Talk in this room: [Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163124/debug-django-code)

Comment: Reputation is less, I need 20, I am new so cant join the chat group.:(

Comment: I checked the code with new env's but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As what Chiheb Nexus [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48246966/1116098), you need to create an admin model for your `UserProfile`. Additionally, you might need to subclass `UserCreationForm`, `UserChangeForm`, and `UserAdmin` in order to reflect the additional fields you have in your `UserProfile` model in Django Admin.

In `admin.py`, try doing something like this.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms

class UserProfileCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    description = forms.CharField()
    city = forms.CharField()
    website = forms.URLField()
    phone = forms.IntegerField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserProfileCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.description = self.cleaned_data['description']
        user.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
        user.website = self.cleaned_data['website']
        user.phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User  # Should this be UserProfile instead of User?
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'description', 'city', 'website', 'phone', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')


class UserProfileChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    description = forms.CharField()
    city = forms.CharField()
    website = forms.URLField()
    phone = forms.IntegerField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserProfileChangeForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.description = self.cleaned_data['description']
        user.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
        user.website = self.cleaned_data['website']
        user.phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User  # Again, should we use UserProfile instead?
        exclude = ('',)


class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = UserProfileChangeForm
    add_form = UserProfileCreationForm
    list_filter = UserAdmin.list_filter + ('description', 'city', 'website', 'phone', )

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'description', 'city', 'website', 'phone', )}),
        (('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'description', 'city', 'website', 'phone', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')}
        ),
    )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

Also, I'm not sure but you might have to change your `UserProfile` model to something like this.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    User.add_to_class('description', models.CharField(max_length=100, default=''))
    User.add_to_class('city', models.CharField(max_length=100, default=''))
    User.add_to_class('website', models.URLField(default=''))
    User.add_to_class('phone', models.IntegerField(default=0))

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # Or user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    # and maybe set unique to True.
```

Comment: Really thanks for your code. But still not getting register. Thanks for your effort @seanFrancis N. Ballais

Comment: And you are using the edited `UserProfile` class I provided, right?

Comment: Ya, I configured for my own environment

Comment: And still, the admin doesn't show the additional fields?

Comment: As mentioned earlier, try printing `admin.site._registry[UserProfile]`. If it says that `admin` is undefined, import `admin` first from `django.contrib` by doing `from django.contrib import admin`.

Comment: In order to verify, I created a new env and checked whether it is working and the code doesn't work.